# Rpam ruby module and PAM service name

Tags: ruby, pam

It appears that the best PAM module for ruby is "rpam". However this module hard codes the service name "rpam" when calling pam_start which seems to be denied by default on at least RHEL. I can get rpam to work by hacking the source to change the hardcoded service name to something present in /etc/pam.d.

Do people normally reconfigure PAM to make use of rpam? Is there a better PAM module out there? (It needs to work with Ruby 1.9.) Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Google isn't giving me much for Rpam.  Is it the same as http://ruby-pam.sourceforge.net/ruby-pam.html?  If not, do you have a link?  And what are your thoughts on one vs the other?

Comment: If you're still looking, I've created a Ruby 1.9 compatible fork called [rpam-ruby19](https://rubygems.org/gems/rpam-ruby19).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having researched more, it looks to me like people normally add an rpam file to /etc/pam.d/.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a PAM config file in `/etc/pam.d`. An easy way would be to copy the existing `login` config.

```
# root required
cp /etc/pam.d/login /etc/pam.d/rpam
```

You can also use rpam2 gem, which lets you specify the PAM service in the function call

```
# 'login' is the used pam service; if nil 'rpam' is used 
Rpam2.auth('login', user, password)
```

Sorry for being 12 years late.